# iTextSharp vertical page fill

Tags: c#, java, itext

I'm trying to find something like `\vfill` from Latex in iTextSharp (a way to insert spaces and place text at the bottom of the page). It's only for one page, not a footer.

I searched online and in the book iText in Action, but didn't find any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a long time and trying many things, I have found a solution.

Some things I tried that "worked", but not good enough:

First I calculated the height of my paragraph (by writing it in a new table in a new document in the RAM), then I would add newlines until there was just enough room for my text. Result: NOT a good way, the text would by off by a few points (the y position in the document, because of the newlines).

Then I tried to do this with `ColumnText`: too many calculations (since my document is dynamic) and I didn't like positioning it absolute.

So my solution is to use a PdfPTable:

```
            var t = new PdfPTable(1);
            t.ExtendLastRow = true;
            t.WidthPercentage = 100; 

            var c = new PdfPCell();
            c.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
            c.DisableBorderSide(Rectangle.BOX);

            var p = new Paragraph("This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.");
            p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;

            c.AddElement(p);

            t.AddCell(c);

            doc.Add(t);
```

Pretty simple, but I lost a lot of time on this. I hope this helps others too.